# Not able to invoke methods on object returned by Doctrine query

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am new to doctrine ORM and I am facing a weird issue i.e. when doctrine query returns an object say a 'Person' (Which is an Entity) then after having its reference I'm not able to invoke Person's getter/settor methods.

Here is my code snippet.

```
 $sql = "SELECT p from Model\Person p where p.name='$name'";

 $query = $em->createQuery($sql);

 $result = $query->getSingleResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_OBJECT);
```

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: It does work for me when I use "SELECT p from Person where name='$name'"

Comment: Yeah that's suppose to work, i have worked with Hibernate but that's altogether different thing because JAVA is type safe and PHP is not, so do we need some settings while getting EntityManager to make this work.